# Rails: render video from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, render

I have the following problem

i'm trying to do this

```
def webm
  @url = Video.find(params[:id]).avatar.url(:webm_sd)
  render json: @url
end
```

but that can not be used in something like this

```
<source src='http://localhost:3000/api/v1/webm?id="+videoId+"' type='video/webm'>
```

cause the type it waits is video not string .. i need a way to render video instead of json

Comment: what about video_tag? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-video_tag  or you need the video by javascript with json ?

Comment: i'm injecting the result in javascript file :)

Comment: is it possible to use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you want to link to a video file using a get parameter? e.g. url?video_id=x? Then simply redirect to the correct video file in your controller using `redirect_to` That should work.